# Strange folding in Vim when there's a { and a } on the same line.&*

Tags: vim, folding

I am currently editing a C++ file with twp function similar to

```
int func_name_1(int param) {
   do_stuff();
   and_more();
}

int func_name_2(int param) {
   do_different_stuff();

   STRUCT_TYPE s = {5, 8, 10, 12};
   do_something_with(s);
}
```

If I do a `zc` on the word `func_name_1`, vim folds the function, as expected, so that it now looks like

```
int func_name_1(int param) {--------------------
```

On `func_name_2` however, the function is folded like so:

```
int func_name_2(int param) {---------------------
   do_something_with(s);
}
```

which is not exactly what I want. For some reason the opening and closing {} on one line seem to disturb the folding algortithm.

If someone knows how I can get a "better" folding, I'd appreciate any hinter into the right direction.

*Edit* the options that I believe are relevant for this problem are set in my buffer like so

```
set foldmarker={,}
set foldmethod=marker
set foldtext=getline(v:foldstart)
```

*Edit II*: If I change the line with the opening and closing {...} to `STRUCT_TYPE s = { 5, 8, 10, 12};` (Note the space after the `{`), then the folding works as expected.

Comment: What is the value of `foldminlines`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh.... I see....

`:help fold-marker` tells me: *Markers can have a level included [..] The following number specifies the fold
level*

So, the `5` immediatly after the `{` specified the fold level, which messed things up.

Comment: Is there any method to disable the fold marker level include ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `zc` command closes the current fold. You may have a folder created to be able to close it, so your problem was on creating the fold and not closing it.

To create the fold use `zf` or `zF`. `zf` Works on visual mode, and also on a motion like `zf2j` to create a fold on 2 lines down. `zF` already works in a "line-wise" way.

The most practical way, in your case, would be to position the cursor on the bracket (using `f{` for example) and run `zf%` to create and close a fold that goes to the matching bracket. Anyway, it would be even more practical if that bracket was on another line (so you could use `]]` to go to it) but that's a convention out of the scope of this answer :-)

Comment: He has not set `foldmethod=manual` but `foldmethod=marker` with a custom marker.